# Using ParaSCIP (UG) in PySCIPOpt

Tags: python, scip

I was wondering how to install and use ParaSCIP (UG) in python for SCIP Optimizer. I've looked through available information and haven't seen any information if UG is implemented in PySCIPOpt. Also default win distribution of SCIP Optimization Suite lacks ParaSCIP. I've tried to build it by myself but failed because of the following error:

```
Makefile.doit:176: recipe for target 'C:/my_progs/11/scipoptsuite-6.0.0/soplex/lib/libsoplex...gnu.opt.a' failed
```

Has anyone succeeded in installing parallel SCIP?

I'm on Windows 10, using Jupyter, Anaconda, Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

UG is not (yet) officially supported on Windows. In the meantime, I recommend you use [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). This should allow you to run the entire SCIP Optimization Suite on Windows.

As for [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt), it's not possible to call UG from Python. We would be happy to work on a Pull Request in that direction :-)

Comment: You should probably suggest to use Pyscipopt to write out the model in mps-format, and then read and solve it with FiberSCIP.